# How to make eleventy include assets such as CSS and images in the output?

Tags: eleventy

I'm trying out the eleventy static site generator for the first time. Whenever I build, the content files are generated just fine, but none of the assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) end up in the output directory - all that appears is the HTML, with broken links to the assets.

For now I'm using the default directory structure:

- project/

  - _includes/
  - _site/
  - css/
  - index.html
  - node_modules/
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json

I've tried building it just like it is above, and I've tried putting the css in the _includes directory. I also tried putting the css in the output folder (_site/), and that worked, but it seems wrong to have to edit a source file in the output.

I've searched around, but none of the tutorials I've found ever address things like including CSS.

Is there a proper way to go about this that I'm missing, or are you really supposed to edit files in both the source and the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was to use [passthrough file copy](https://www.11ty.io/docs/copy/). I hadn't looked into that before because, as a beginner, it seemed like an advanced topic, and I figured something as basic as getting your CSS into the output directory should be some simple setting that's turned on by default. It *is* simple once you know how to do it, but it's not a default for some reason.

Here's the code that fixed my problem. "_src/assets" is the folder holding all the CSS and images, relative to the project root.

```
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {

    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("_src/assets");

    return {
        dir: {
            includes: "_templates",
            input: "_src",
            output: "_site"
        }
    };

};
```